# Jenkins + sbt-assembly + Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, sbt-assembly

We have the following:

1) Jenkins + Artifactory + Java + Spark(scala)

Our goal is to publish an uber jar to our artifactory repo by using sbt-assembly or the like.

We have two Java Maven projects being built by Jenkins and published to Artifactory.

We have a Spark/Scala project which depends upon the two Java Maven Projects and is able to be built with Jenkins with the following sbt commands:

1) clean assembly : builds an uber jar file in the projects/target dir, yet "**does not**" publish to our artifactory repo

2) clean publish : builds a standard jar file (no dependencies) and "**does**" publish the stamdard jar file to our artifactory repo.

3) clean assembly publish : does both 1 & 2 yet only publishes the standard jar file to artifactory repo.

Our **Build.sbt** is large (Contents regarding repo):

```
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://artifactory_company.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local")

credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "artifactory_company.com", "admin", "admin!")

isSnapshot := true
```

**project/plugins.sbt :**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0-RC2")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.2")

resolvers += Resolver.url("artifactory", url("http://artifactory_company.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Any assistance is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Please try to properly format the code inside your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6321858/user239463 I'm hoping you resolved this, did you? could you post the answer?